# How to construct a set of m x n matrices where no two elements share the same row twice.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

## Part 1:

Say I have an $m$ by $n$ matrix, where each element is unique. I want to find the largest set of matrices created by permuting this matrix where no two elements appear in the same row more than once.

For example, with a $3$ by $3$ matrix, here are some valid permutations:

*Permutation 1:*

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & b & c\\
d & e & f\\
g & h & i
\end{matrix}\right)$$

*Permutation 2:*

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & h & f\\
d & b & i\\
g & e & c
\end{matrix}\right)$$

*Permuation 3:*

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & e & i\\
d & h & c\\
g & b & f
\end{matrix}\right)$$

***Not*** a valid permutation (the pairs $(a,c)$ and $(h,i)$ have already been together):

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a & e & c\\
d & h & i\\
g & b & f
\end{matrix}\right)$$

A square $3$ by $3$ matrix has at least four valid permutations, maybe more (I don't know). How would I figure this out for a non-square matrix with $m$ by $n$ dimensions, especially larger matrices, like $10$ by $6$, or $8$ by $10$?

## Part 2:

This is a similar question. Imagine an $m$ by $n$ matrix, where $m$ and $n$ are greater than or equal to $4$. The matrix is filled like this:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
a_1 & b_2 & c_3 & d_4 & f_1\\
a_2 & b_3 & c_4 & e_1 & f_2\\
a_3 & b_4 & d_1 & e_2 & f_3\\
a_4 & c_1 & d_2 & e_3 & f_4\\
b_1 & c_2 & d_3 & e_4 & g_1\\
\end{matrix}\right)$$

where $a$, $b$, $c$, etc. are sets of numbers, each of length $4$. The matrix is filled by column, and the last set is truncated if necessary (only the first element of $g$ is shown in the example matrix).

How can I find the set of matrices for a matrix like this, with the same constraints as in Part 1, only in addition, elements that are members of the same set *cannot* be on the same row?

Comment: Not sure I understand. What's wrong with these four permutations? $$\left(\begin{matrix}a & b & c\\d & e & f\\g & h & i\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a & d & g\\b & e & h\\c & f & i\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}a & e & i\\b & f & g\\c & d & h\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix}
a & f & h\\b & d & i\\c & e & g\end{matrix}\right)$$

Comment: This first part looks to be a form of the [Kirkman Schoolgirl problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirkman%27s_schoolgirl_problem). But this is an example of [combinatorial design](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design), *not* a simple counting problem. i.e. "How many" is kind of the wrong question because that may depend on how you construct the matrices, a better one is "how do we construct matrices in order to maximise the set of such matrices with no two elements in the same row twice?" There will be several different ways to do this

Comment: @bof Oh. Yep. You're right. I changed the question

Comment: @N.Shales Thanks. I edited my question. Does this make more sense?

Comment: Yes, that is better. If you see the link for the Kirkman schoolgirl problem you will see that you can get a maximum of $7$ 3 by 3 matrices in such a set. I'm not sure about the second part (I'm only beginning to look at combinatorial design).

Comment: Sorry, the Kirkman schoolgirl problem would be equivalent to 3 by 5 (not 3 by 3) matrices. Have a look at the link, it is a good starting place.